# Why won't my return statement work?

Tags: java, for-loop, return, return-value, probability

I'm trying to get it to return a value. What I want is for it to return the total of a bunch of numbers that are auto-generated in other parts of the program.

```
   public static double totalAmount(double probability, int numOfSuccesses){
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfSuccesses; i++){
         double total= 0;
         total += probability;
      }
   }
   return total;
```

When I do that, I get:

```
binomialDistribution.java:37: error: illegal start of type
   return total;
```

Comment: It is outside the method body....

Comment: How do you like to obtain the "total of a bunch of numbers" when you send a single number to that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your example: the return statement is outside the function scope and `total` is declared within the loop.

It should be something like this:

```
public static double totalAmount(double probability, int numOfSuccesses){
    double total= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSuccesses; i++){
        total += probability;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function only calculates a simple multiplication:

```java
public static double totalAmount(double probability, int numOfSuccesses) {
    return probability * numOfSuccesses;
}
```

Well, in a little bit more complicated way.

Comment: OP didn't ask for alternatives, he/she asked as to why the code isn't working!

Comment: Actually an indirect answer: The smaller code, the lower probability of misplaced returns and misplaced variable initializations. ;-)